# Using win64 unwinding data directives in VSYASM

Tags: assembly, x86-64, yasm

The code all worked fine, but then I added [directives to create unwinding data](http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/objfmt-win64-exception.html), and YASM started refusing to assemble my code.

The build settings are for x64, as proven by "-f x64" in the auto-generated command line: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\"vsyasm.exe -Xvc -f x64 -o "x64\Debug\\" -l "" -P "" --mapdir= "" -E "" --prefix "" --suffix "" -rnasm -pnasm -m amd64`

Normally the `-m` switch isn't in there, but I added it for good measure. That didn't help.

Changing the argument of the `-f` switch to `win64` doesn't help either: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\"vsyasm.exe -Xvc -f win64 -o "x64\Debug\\" -l "" -P "" --mapdir= "" -E "" --prefix "" --suffix "" -rnasm -pnasm -m amd64`

In this code,

```
    bits 64
    global s24_fl32_sse2_win64
s24_fl32_sse2_win64:
    proc_frame s24_fl32_sse2_win64
    sub rsp, 8 + 4 * 16
    [alloc_stack 8 + 4 * 16]
    movdqa [rsp], xmm6
    [save_xmm128 xmm6, 0]
    [endprolog]
```

VSYASM complains about a redefinition of the function label, which probably means that it didn't recognize `proc_frame` as a directive. It also says `error: unrecognized directive 'alloc_stack'` and the same for `save_xmm128`. It doesn't complain about `endprolog`.

Putting the `proc_frame` in brackets makes the first error go away (the label re-definition), but the manual says to use it without brackets, and it doesn't solve the problem anyway.

How do I fix this? Preferably in a way that creates proper unwind data.

Comment: Your -f option looks wrong, that ought to be -f win64.

Comment: @HansPassant I have tried that too and that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `PROC_FRAME` defines the label, so you don't need the `s24_fl32_sse2_win64:` line - also a few examples I've seen put `global s24_fl32_sse2_win64` after the `PROC_FRAME` - I'm not sure whether this is required or not.

In addition - `alloc_stack` and `save_xmm128` (without square brackets) are macros (they handle both the stack operation itself and the related unwind primitive) - the unwind primitive versions of these are `[allocstack ....]` and `[savexmm128....]`.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed everything. I can't award the bounty yet, though.